# How to obtain information from onHandleIntent (Android)

Tags: android, android-intent, toast

I´m working on my `IntentService`, in which I generate values in a loop. In overriden methods `onStartCommand()` and `onDestroy()`, there is possible to display a message using `Toast`. I would like to use `Toast` also in `onHandleIntent()`, but it´s not working. I know there are better ways (files, attributes etc.) to display values, but I need these values immediately, when they are created. Not in the end (only for control, if it´s working properly). Please, can you help me identify the problem? Thanks in advance.

```
public class HelloIntentService extends IntentService {

  public HelloIntentService() {
      super("HelloIntentService");
  }

  @Override
  public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
      Toast.makeText(this, "service starting", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      return super.onStartCommand(intent,flags,startId);
  }

  @Override
  protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {

      long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis() + 5*1000;
      while (System.currentTimeMillis() < endTime) {
          synchronized (this) {
              try {
                  wait(endTime - System.currentTimeMillis());
              } catch (Exception e) {
              }
          }
      }}

  @Override
  public void onDestroy()
  {
      Toast.makeText(this, "Service is being destroyed now.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  }
}
```

Comment: plz add IntentService code also

Comment: try to show toast as : `Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "service starting",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();`

Comment: It works. I´ve found that problem appeared only when I put `Toast` into the code in onHandleIntent. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

onHandleIntent runs on a separate thread in the background per [the source code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/app/IntentService.java) and therefore does not have any ability to update the UI. I would suggest using logging statements, rather than Toasts to display your information:

```
Log.d("HelloIntentService","service starting");
```